# Nerdtree display current opened file after jumping into a tag

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

I'm not sure if this is possible, I have my nerdtree opened for file let's say main.cpp. Then I use tag jump to one of the definitions which is in a different directory but nerdtree window still shows my original tree and underlines main.cpp. But i would like nerdtree to display my tag location and underline the current file.

eg:

```
*Project/    |
 *include/   |   int main() {
 *src/       |     Example ex;  //i use tag jump to Example which is in Project/include/external/header.h 
  test.cpp   |   return 0;
  main.cpp   |   }
```

After vim jumped to the tag, I do see the header.h but also would like to see something below

```
*Project/    |
 *include/   |
  *external/ |
    header.h | <-I want nerdtree would display this that opens and 'hightlight' the latest opened file
 *src/       |
  test.cpp   |
  main.cpp   |
```

Even if I tried to refresh nerdtree it won't auto-expand include for me, is there any way that can do this?

Comment: The `:NERDTreeFind` command will make NERDTree open folders to display the current file. You could possibly use an autocommand to run that after opening a new file. I just bound it to a quick mapping so I could use it easily when I wanted it.

Comment: Thanks @tommcdo. Great suggestion, I can add an additional key mapping for that.